# htaccess no fuciona con Virtual host con Xampp

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, xampp, mod-rewrite

Tengo un error con el servidor en local, no me funciona las urls amigables con .htaccess, antes usaba mamp pro y no pedía nada, ahora en ubuntu 16.04 he montado un servidor con XAMPP, para las urls amigables he tenido que montar el VirtualHost, tengo activado el modulo de rewrite

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

pero aun asi no funciona, en la carpeta tengo .htaccess con

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/error404
</IfModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript application/javascript
<ifmodule deflate_module.c>
    DeflateCompressionLevel 1
    DeflateBufferSize 8096
    DeflateMemLevel 8
    DeflateWindowSize 8

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

siempre me esta cargando la pagina de error404 por el !mod_rewrite.c y en el httpd-vhosts.conf no tengo nada que impida usar el htaccess.

```
#localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin you@localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs
    ServerName localhost:80
    ErrorLog logs/localhost-error_log
    CustomLog logs/localhost-access_log common

</VirtualHost>

#seiku.es
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin you@seiku.es
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/seiku/codeigniter
    ServerName seiku.es
    ServerAlias www.seiku.es
    ErrorLog logs/seiku-error_log
    CustomLog logs/seiku-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

Cualquier ayuda será agradecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que en tu archivo `.htaccess` hay una direcitva que dice "si no está cargado el módulo `mod_rewrite.c` muestrame la pagina de **error 404**.

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/error404
</IfModule>
```

Por lo tanto... **el módulo mod_rewrite.c no está cargado**.

En Apache2 los módulos se cargan con un enlace blando desde `/etc/apache2/mods_availabe/` a `/etc/apache2/mods_enabled` Si no tienes el enlace a mod_rewrite en el directorio enabled, ahí está el problema. O si no has reiniciado apache tras modificar la configuración:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Comment: Al parecer si que estaba activado el modulo rewrite, tan solo que linux es Case sensitive mientras que windows no lo es, había un error por documentos php no los encontraba y lanzaba el error 404 y los directorios dentro de 
`
^application.*
phppass.php -->Phppass.php
class phpass --> class Phpass
`
Muchas gracias Ricardo, me ha servido mucho para estudiar sobre apache

Comment: jajaja, pues era otra posibilidad. Conste que lo que se me ocurre ahora para la siguiente.... es preparar una plantilla para el error 404 distinta para el caso de no encontrar  mod_rewrite. XD